# Where are iSCSI and volume information location on ESX 4.0?

Tags: vmware-esx

Let me start by saying I am somewhat of a Vmware novice, I know just enought to manage and create servers at a basic level from the vSphere client. 
I have a VMWare server, ESX 4.0 connected over iSCSI to a SAN. The SAN is being used as storage for both RDMs and VMFS volumes.

The SAN has died and I ordered a new one. Where can I see the settings related to the iSCSI and volume configuration so that I can try and replicate them on the new SAN when it arrives?

Comment: There are, quite literally, books on how to integrate your storage infrastructure into a VMWare environment. If you have no experience with iSCSI or a SAN in general, you really aren't ready to do this. You should hire a consultant with experience and grab a book or two on the topic in the meantime. Scott Lowe has written some very good books on vSphere, for example.

Comment: Thanks MDMarra. I have a litte experience with this sort of thing, and was hoping for some advice on getting pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I completely understand that. The problem is that the storage back-end is probably the most critical part of integration with vSphere (or VI in this case). "How do I hook my VMWare host up to a SAN" is something that is heavily dependent on your environment and doesn't really have a clear-cut answer. The [faq] says `"Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."` In this case, there are actual books on this.

Comment: @MDMarra, shoot, and I was hoping that since it had been previously set up, I might just find the ip configuration that was in use and replicate that on the new server and have it up and running in no time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading through your most recent comments, if all that you want to see is the configuration of your *current* settings, you can do this.

Connect using the VI client. Navigate to the Network section and Storage section in the Configuration tab. It's all there. That said, there are probably a lot of things you'll have to change to make it work like CHAP settings, LUN mappings, etc. On the SAN you'll also have to configure LUN masking, etc. It's really not like "Ok, I'll plug this bad boy in and go." A SAN failure is a major replacement.

Comment: You sir are correct, That is the configuration I was looking for. And you are also correct in assuming I probably need some professional help in this situation. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If you have some spare training dollars, you should grab a copy of Mastering vSphere 5 by Scott Lowe. It's for a version newer than what you're on, but it's one of the best tech books I've read on the topic.

Comment: There's also here to at least get you started: http://mylearn.vmware.com/portals/www/mL.cfm?menu=topfreecourses

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what MDMarra said above - what you are trying to do may or may not be possible based on a number of things that you haven't told us (like if you have backups of the data, etc. etc.)  However, you might be able to pull additional information to what you would get out of the VI client by running the following commands

(pulled from http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=1013283 )

Retrieving the iSCSI Database

You can dump the entire iSCSI database to a file using this command:

vmkiscsid --dump-db= 
Listing Running/Active Targets

To list currently running targets, run this command:

vmkiscsi-tool -T vmhba##

Listing Discovered Targets

The following command lists all targets that have been discovered but that may not be logged in or active:

vmkiscsi-tool -T vmhba##

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why backup data would even matter at this point. I will rebuild virtual servers as needed, and they aren't. this was more of a disaster recovery platform, waiting for VMs to be cloned turned on etc. I will take a look at these commands and see what info I can get out of the deal. Thanks

Comment: Backup data would matter if you wanted to recover any of the actual data that was lost when your SAN died, after recreating volumes/LUNs.  Since you seem to just want to re-do your iscsi target settings instead of setting it up fresh, that may not be of use to you.  the level of information that you need is highly dependant on what your goals are, and that isn't really clear from your question or comments.

Comment: Yes I believe that is the term I am looking for Iscsi target. I unfortunately am unfamiliar with the esx / vmware terminology so it makes it hard for me to clearly state what I want. I will however try, I just want the SAN to be recognized by the ESX server as a live iscsi target. one step at a time while I wait for professional help to show up.